# How to remove flange from bottom of toilet

Tags: toilet, flange

[image]I’m trying to replace the seal on my toilet. When I lifted the toilet off the floor the flange stayed on the bottom of the commode. I cannot figure out how to remove the flange.I’ve tried pulling and twisting with no success. How can I remove the flange?

Comment: You'll need to post photos so we can see what's going on - both of bottom of toilet (with flange) and of the in the floor.

Comment: It is screwed to the floor with 4 screws

Comment: @Ruskes  I do not think those screws held.  OP lifted toilet with the flange, or something.  Pictures will help.

Comment: You removed the two bolts holding the toilet. Then you lifted the toilet. There is a metal flange with 2 rods sticking up. So far so good. You do not need to remove the flange if the bolts are still there and in good shape. If you have to remove the metal flange it is screwed to the floor with 4 screws, that might be rotten.

Comment: The _flange_ is still on the floor.   You are looking at the bottom of the toilet that rests on the wax ring.

Comment: @SteveWellens (*et al.*) actually, that looks like a flange spacer in the photo. https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey-closet-flange-spacers--1163854821 I think the black part between the disc and the toilet horn is one of the gaskets in the kit.

Comment: @Huesmann When I posted, there was no photo.   I think it is a flange that was USED as a spacer (note the keyhole openings for the bolts)  In any event it should be able to be pried off.   Unless some bozo glued it on.

Comment: @SteveWellens fair enough—no pic.  But it looks *exactly* like the spacer in the link.  Why would someone buy a flange for about the same cost as a spacer, and cut off the "horn" part of it?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Brute force.   That's the answer.  A flat head screwdriver and a hammer?  IDK -- you pick your favorite tools, just try not to break the toilet.

The rest is speculation.

I see a flange extender.  I don't see any wax residue.   Someone used a flange extension, did not secure it to the floor, and used silicone or glue to attach it to the toilet.    Maybe there was wax between the flange and the extension?  Did you clean it off?  REALLY really well?

Anyway you just need to rip that thing off.  Hopefully it's silicone, once you get it started it'll peel off.  If it's glue you might need to chip off bits of plastic one tiny shard at a time with a wood chisel.  Or just get a new toilet.  You don't actually have to clean it up perfectly .... the new wax ring will make a good seal around any small bits left over.

Comment: The black stuff between the flange and toilet outlet and the brown stuff you see through the bolt slots in the flang look like wax.